# Redirecting static to dynamic URL's

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I know this has been asked a few times but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax for our situation.

I am trying to permanently redirect links such as **example.com/work.aspx** to **example.com/work** in the .htaccess file.

Basically converting an *ASP.NET* site to *Wordpress*.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Giles

Comment: Are you just wanting to effectively chop off the `.aspx` suffix from incoming requests so it delivers a WordPress page to the visitor instead...?

Comment: Unfortunately not as we have some URL's that arn't the same structure.

Comment: I have found a plugin that seems like its working now - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/

Comment: I know that doesn't solve the problem for other people who arn't using Wordpress but hope it helps the Wordpress users out.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^(.*).aspx$ /$1 [R=301]